# Linux Ubuntu / Mint Live CD user-home customization

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, livecd, initrd

I'm trying to customize Linux Mint Live CD with [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) instruction (uck doesn't work for me).

What I want is to have more icons at its Live CD user (`/home/mint/Desktop`) but I can't find `/home/mint` on the squashfs filesystem nor at the initrd fs.

The changes I make in `/etc/skel` do not apply either.

What am I missing? (I'm using a lxdm wm.)

Comment: I tried those instruction as well, without getting a bootable result.
I found update instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141305) that work.

Answer (score 1):

I found it: the `livecd` user is generated from the casper scripts residing inside. Look for `10adduser` in the `initrd` file (`.gz` or `.lz` compressed depending on the distro).

Much more data is available at [live-debian](http://live.debian.net/manual/).